# iTunes tab and space key behavior

Tags: itunes, keyboard

I have a problem that I thought I knew the solution to, but apparently do not.

Somehow, in the past few days, I did something to change the behavior of the tab key and the spacebar when controlling iTunes. The space bar, when pressed in Miniplayer, closes Miniplayer and returns to the full app display, rather than play/pause (space remains play/pause in the full app--it does not return you to Miniplayer when pressed again). The tab key now moves between nearly every control on the screen, where previously it only transferred between text boxes and lists.

The first obvious thought I had was to go to the keyboard control panel/shortcuts and make sure that "Text boxes and lists only" was selected for Tab focus. *This setting is correct* - the behavior in iTunes acts as though "All controls" is selected, even though it is not.

So, the easy fix isn't working for me, and I need the next idea. Whatchya'll got?

Comment: Having the same issue...might have something to do with the search field...still clueless though...